# WSO2: Point-to-Point Messaging

Tags: java, jmeter, wso2

I am following this tutorial https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Point-to-Point+Messaging#865c10b8d4d64ac688d6a0799cfb6012

and after reaching Step 2 i.e. running the JMS Publisher I am getting the error in JMeter that

[image]

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-09-25 06:11:40 NPT
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1209
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1209
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 000
Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory  [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory ]


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

I have followed the required jar files as instructed in Jmeter lib folder, also I am running Jmeter with Admin permissions.

Still I am getting this error:

`Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory  [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory ]`

How can I fix this? What am I missing?

After providing jar in test plan, browse option (so that I don't have to restart), still it is giving class not found error. Here are the logs:

```
2019-09-25 15:10:19,299 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Requesting https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/?installID=docker-461b0856afade2414c8e3dfbab5ca751-gui
2019-09-25 15:10:20,264 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-09-25 15:10:20,266 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-09-25 15:10:20,266 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-09-25 15:10:20,266 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-09-25 15:10:20,266 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2019-09-25 15:10:20,267 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2019-09-25 15:10:22,056 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
2019-09-25 15:10:22,057 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file E:\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\proxyserver.jks
2019-09-25 15:10:22,781 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='C:\Windows\system32'
2019-09-25 15:10:25,004 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2019-09-25 15:10:25,004 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2019-09-25 15:10:25,004 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2019-09-25 15:10:25,004 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2019-09-25 15:10:28,324 WARN o.j.r.PluginManagerMenuItem: Failed to load plugin updates info
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:131) ~[jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:1.7.25]
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache.process(RequestAuthCache.java:77) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:133) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:167) ~[httpcore-4.4.10.jar:4.4.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:484) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:499) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:494) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJSON(JARSourceHTTP.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepositories(JARSourceHTTP.java:276) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getRepo(JARSourceHTTP.java:304) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:71) ~[jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem$1.run(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:41) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar:?]
2019-09-25 15:18:30,504 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: F:\Training\MQ\MQPubslisher.jmx
2019-09-25 15:18:30,505 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='F:\Training\MQ'
2019-09-25 15:18:31,128 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2019-09-25 15:18:31,168 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2019-09-25 15:18:31,171 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2019-09-25 15:18:31,178 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: F:\Training\MQ\MQPubslisher.jmx
2019-09-25 15:18:32,513 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='F:\Training\MQ'
2019-09-25 15:27:32,675 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='F:\Training\MQ'
2019-09-25 15:28:58,900 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-09-25 15:28:58,902 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-09-25 15:28:58,903 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-09-25 15:28:58,950 INFO o.a.j.t.TestPlan: added E:\apache-jmeter-5.0\lib\andes-client-4.0.0.jar to classpath
2019-09-25 15:28:58,952 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-09-25 15:28:59,559 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-09-25 15:28:59,564 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-09-25 15:28:59,565 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-09-25 15:28:59,566 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2019-09-25 15:28:59,590 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-09-25 15:28:59,590 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-09-25 15:28:59,593 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-09-25 15:28:59,759 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-09-25 15:28:59,760 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-09-25 15:28:59,761 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-09-25 15:28:59,766 INFO o.a.j.p.j.c.InitialContextFactory: InitialContextFactory.close() called and Context instances cleaned up
2019-09-25 15:28:59,766 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to **restart JMeter** for any property change and when you add .jars under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), otherwise the changes will not be picked up.

---

According to [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter/) article it should be also possible to add the libraries to JMeter Classpath at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level like:

[image]

in that case JMeter restart will not be required

Comment: It is still giving error. I have added logs in original question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solve it by removing a whitespace at the end of the Initial Context Factory field.